# Parsing PostgreSQL response from any() into JS object

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg-promise, node-postgres

When I call:

`db.any('SELECT (col1, col2, col3) FROM myTable....[other conditions]')`

where **db** is an instance of pg-promise connection, as a promise result for

`.then(function(data)) {`

I get an array with objects like `{ row: '(ans1,ans2,ans3)' }`

It is also written in [pg-promise documentation](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#any)

Is there any convenient way (i.e. without string triming and coma splitting) to parse it to JS object? I would like to use it in views (.pug files), for example `element.col1` which will print ans1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By wrapping column names into `()`, you are specifically requesting exactly what you are getting back.

Without `()` you will get an array of JSON objects.